# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.generic to <ProjectNamespace.List>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```cs
namespace Automated_VotingSystem.Models
{
    public class DisplayCandidatesList
    {
        public List<DisplayCandidates>? DisplayCandidateslist { get; set;}
    }
}

namespace Automated_VotingSystem.Models
{
    public partial class DisplayCandidates
    {
        public int VoterId { get; set; }
        public int? CollegeId { get; set; }
        public int? EventId { get; set; }
        public int CandidateId { get; set; }
        public string? Manifesto { get; set; }
        public byte[]? Symbol { get; set; }
        public string? Symbol_path { get; set; }        
    }
}

public List<DisplayCandidates> DisplayCandidateslist { get; set; }

[HttpGet("[action]/{GetAllCandidates}")]
public async Task<DisplayCandidatesList> DisplayAllCandidates()
{
    var list_of_candidates = (from c in _context.CandidateTables
                              join ac in _context.ApprovedCandidateTables on c.CandidateId equals ac.CandidateId
                              join s in _context.SymbolTables on c.SymbolId equals s.SymbolId
                              where ac.Approval == true
                              select new
                              {
                                  candidate_id = ac.CandidateId,
                                  manifesto = c.Manifesto,
                                  symbol_path = s.Symbol_path
                              }).ToList();
    return  list_of_candidates;
}
```

The 1st snippet is my class, 2nd snippet is my model and 3rd snippet is my Controller. While executing the code I am getting a error after returning list of candidates as

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int? candidate_id,
> string manifesto, string symbol_path>>' to
> 'Automated_VotingSystem.Models.DisplayCandidatesList'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your the DisplayAllCandidates method is expecting a list of DisplayCandidates. Therefore, use explicit type DisplayCandidates instead of anonymous and change the action return type to List< DisplayCandidate >>. And since it is  an async action, it is better to use an async return

```
public async Task<List<DisplayCandidates>> DisplayAllCandidates()
{
    return await (from c in _context.CandidateTables
                              
                         ....
                              select new DisplayCandidates
                              {
                                  CandidateId = ac.CandidateId,
                                  Manifesto = c.Manifesto,
                                  Symbol_path = s.Symbol_path
                              }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to do here,But It seems ; You dont need "DisplayCandidatesList" class, you only need one "DisplayCandidates" class.
If you use this class in another class as a form of list,use like that List instead of List? ,But here you dont need that I guess.

Your list method can return "Task<List>" like that,
I suggest you to study topic Collections and Generics in C#
And dont use that naming in Controllers actions check naming standarts
https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Comment: I have 3 different entities in my model Candidates, symbol and Approval, Candidates and symbol have primary key, here I am trying to inner-join the tables and create Some action to pass it to front end, thank you for your reply and the link.